# How to access JAAS user in EL

Tags: jsf, el, jaas

I'm using JAAS for authentication and autorization and I don't know how to access the information of the current user..When I use Filter I do something like this : `<h:outputText value="#{sessionScope['user'].nom}"></h:outputText>` but with JAAS authentification I cant do the same :\ I want to get user session information to use them in EJB to insert some value into my database.(excuse me for my bad english :\ )
You can find here my login method :

```
 public String loginn() throws Exception{

          String message = "";
          String navto = "" ;
          HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
          try
          { //Login via the Servlet Context
          request.login(username, password);
          //Retrieve the Principal
          Principal principal = request.getUserPrincipal();
          if(principal == null){
                throw new Exception("Invalid user/password");
            }

          //Display a message based on the User role

          if
          (request.isUserInRole("Administrator" )){
         message = "Username : " + principal.getName() + " You are an Administrator, you can really many things up now";
         navto = "admin";
         }
          else
          if
          (request.isUserInRole("Manager")){
         message = "Username : " + principal.getName() + " You are only a Manager, Don't you have a Spreadsheet to be working on??" ;
          navto = "manager" ;
          }
          else
          if
          (request.isUserInRole("Guest")){
         message = "Username : " + principal.getName() +  " You're wasting my resources..."  ;
          navto ="guest";
          }
         //Add the welcome message to the faces context
         FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage( null , new  FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, message, null ));
         return navto;
         }
          catch
          (ServletException e) {
         FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage( null ,new  FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,"An Error Occured: Login failed" , null ));
         e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return "failure" ;
```

Thank you for help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user name is available by [`HttpServletRequest#getRemoteUser()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRemoteUser()). See also the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRemoteUser()):

> #### getRemoteUser
>
> `String getRemoteUser()`
>
> Returns the login of the user making this request, if the user has been authenticated, or `null` if the user has not been authenticated. Whether the user name is sent with each subsequent request depends on the browser and type of authentication. Same as the value of the CGI variable `REMOTE_USER`.

In EL, the current `HttpServletRequest` is available as `#{request}`. See also [implicit EL objects](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ImplicitELObjects). You can just access getters on it the same way as with regular javabeans.

```
#{request.remoteUser}
```

So e.g. this should do:

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{empty request.remoteUser}">
    <p>You're not logged in. <h:link outcome="login">Please login</h:link>.</p>
</ui:fragment>
<ui:fragment rendered="#{not empty request.remoteUser}">
    <p>Welcome, #{request.remoteUser}!</p>
</ui:fragment>
```

Equivalently, user roles are available by `#{request.isUserInRole(...)}` as follows:

```
<h:commandButton value="Delete" action="#{bean.delete}" 
    rendered="#{request.isUserInRole('Administrator')}" />
```

Comment: I have just seen your answer thank you so much @BalusC

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your JSF page : `request.getUserPrincipal()` .

Comment: Its work for me I hope it will be the same for you .